# Data not storing to sql database from php session start variable

Tags: php, sql, input

I'm trying to store user input in to my sql table as seen below,
[my database http://goawaymom.com/test.png](http://goawaymom.com/test.png)

I query the users for their 'email', 'firstname', 'last name', and 'about' after they register  [here.](http://goawaymom.com/login/register.php) However what ever I do, the user input does not save to the database. I THINK but am NOT sure that this is a problem with my session_start variable. I believe the session is not starting/saving properly unique to the user that has registered. I based my code of this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruoptcAx-BQ&feature=BFa&list=SP074EAEF57B0DA2A4) as I am new to PHP.

editprofile.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include('core/init_inc.php');

if(isset($_POST['email'], $_POST['about'], $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['lastname'])){
$errors = array();   
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
    $errors[] = 'The email address you entered is not valid';    
}
if (empty($errors)){
    set_profile_info($_POST['email'],$_POST['about']);
}
$user_info = array(
    'email'     => htmlentities($_POST['email']),
    'about'     => htmlentities($_POST['about']),
    'firstname'     => htmlentities($_POST['firstname']),
    'lastname'     => htmlentities($_POST['lastname'])
);
} else {
$user_info = fetch_user_info($SESSION['uid']);
}
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Once again my question is, why isn't the data from my editprofile.php form saving in to my php sql database and how do i fix this. Thanks in advance, and if more code is needed then I'd be willing to provide it. The form can be accessed [here](http://goawaymom.com/login/register.php), upon registering for the website.

```
function fetch_users() {
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `user_id` AS `id`, `username` FROM `users`');

$users = array ();

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) !== false){
    $users[ ] = $row;
}


return $users;

}
//fetches profile information for the given user
function fetch_user_info($uid){
$uid = (int)$uid;

$sql = "SELECT
            `username`,
            `user_firstname` AS `firstname`,
            `user_lastname` AS `lastname`,
            `user_about` AS `about`,
            `user_email` AS `email`
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `user_id` = {$uid}";

$result = mysql_query($sql);        
return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);


}

//updates the current user profile info
function set_profile_info($email, $about){
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($email));
$about = mysql_real_escape_string(nl2br(htmlentities($about)));


$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET
        `user_email` = `{$email}`,
        `user_about` = `{about}`
    WHERE `user_id` = {$_SESSION[`uid`]}";
mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you should use mysql_real_escape_string instead of htmlentities.

Comment: There's nothing in your code to write something to the database. Do you do it in `set_profile_info`? In which case, you might want to add the code for that to your question.

Comment: Where's your code that actually attempts to save the user info?  And what does `fetct_user_info()` look like?

Comment: What happens when you echo out your SQL query? Does it run when you run it straight in the database? Also, your UPDATE for `user_about` is using the literal `about`, rather than `{$about}`, though that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: when i echo it out like this?
http://goawaymom.com/login/profile/profile.php?uid=57

Comment: Switch the final `mysql_query($sql)` to `echo($sql)`. That will show you what SQL you're generating. Does it look like you expect?

Comment: i echoe'd it as suggested and it displays the same thing i believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use ` around the strings {$email} and {$about}. Also right now you have {about} instead of {$about}. You are also using it for:

```
$_SESSION[`uid`] //needs to be $_SESSION['uid']
```

So this should be:

```
$sql = "UPDATE `users` SET
        `user_email` = '{$email}',
        `user_about` = '{$about}'
    WHERE `user_id` = {$_SESSION['uid']}";
```

Comment: I did this however it still does not save the information in to my database.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Change `mysql_query($sql)` to `mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error in query: $sql. ".mysql_error());` and see if you get an error.

Comment: no error messages! When I enter information in to edit_profile.php it just doesn't save in to my database

Comment: Have you done a var_dump of $_POST to make sure it is getting the values correctly?

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is you have `fetch_user_info($SESSION['uid'])` should be `fetch_user_info($_SESSION['uid'])` can you echo $sql and paste the result here for us so we can see the query?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17772/discussion-between-neat-and-pitchinnate)